# Arbitrary units or unitless plot to protect data?

Tags: publications, data

My question is about naming semi-arbitrary units in a (conference) paper.

I am writing a paper and, in accordance with advice from my mentor, I need to remove exact data and parameters from most of the paper because some of it is sensitive information. Ideally, I would like to preserve the shape of the plots but make the units arbitrary.

Note that this doesn't in any way interfere with understanding the results. The exact same procedure can be used regardless of the exact parameter value (literally the slope of a line), but we aren't allowed to publish that value.

In one case, I was plotting two curves on the same plot showing the difference in performance between two actuators. I normalized both curves, but then they more or less overlapped, which made the graphic uninteresting and a bit confusing. So, I normalized one plot and then did some relative scaling / biasing of the data to preserve the overall shape somewhat proportionally.

What would I call that? Normalized data? Arbitrary units? Unitless? Should I just make a note that the scale has been adjusted to preserve the shape?

In another case I have two sets of linear fitted data and I am having a similar issue on how to display and label these things, because the units will be rather arbitrary but it won't be quite normalized.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm confused - were the curves not overlapping originally, but became overlapping after normalization? If so you presumably normalized them separately, which would produce that behavior by design, or the scale's off. Standard procedure for arbitrary units is to divide all data by some reference value (e.g. the normalization constant for *one* of the curves). Individual scaling only serves to confuse things. But for your purposes, why not plot the difference (in real, normalized, or arbitrary units) instead of dealing with two curves?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My approach isn't good and I wasn't sure what the standard was. That would be a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: If the parameter doesn’t matter, why don’t you regenerate all data with a different non-secret parameter?

Comment: The data is a measurement of the position of an actuator vs the drive voltage. I cannot regenerate it. The actual value is of interest to those theoretically applying the simulation to the project at hand, but for anyone using the technique, it could be a different value that accords with their particular system. Normalization seems like the way to go.

Comment: You are not the first to publish papers based on sensitive information - check other papers published .. I know of 4 projects  that have been classed as “secret” and they were passed but not made public...

Comment: How can the units on a plot possibly reveal sensitive information? What are you measuring in, "number of dates Josh had last year"?

Comment: Again, I don't make the rules buddy. Use your imagination.

Comment: @Trusly It happens. I remember at least one unitless graph from early in my career, because I was working with people who didn't want to release details of the material properties of the thing I was evaluating. I'm not convinced the secrecy was necessary, but it wasn't my opinion that counted on that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that paper is submitted to [IEEE Transactions on Microwave Theory and Techniques](https://www.mtt.org/) (and judging by comments, this journal should be a decent enough fit for the purpose of this discussion), you would have to provide the measurement results. The journal guidelines explicitly ask for it and no *arbitrary units* or *unitless* plots will suffice.

[Reproducibilty of the research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducibility#Reproducible_research) is very important. And **obfuscating** the data certainly goes against it. If this plot & experiment itself is crucial for the paper – and you are not allowed by any means to disclose the parameters required to reproduce **your experiment** – you don't have a paper. Which might be sad, but that's not "the science" and "scientific process" fault, but ITAR (if that's the case) and yours, by (un)willingly accepting their terms.

One might judge that this is a conference paper, not a full journal one. But I, personally, prefer to have very similar standards for both conference & journal papers – and a lot of conferences have a similar (if not better) review process.

Comment: Thank you for providing the link! This is indeed for a conference paper, not a journal paper. It's for AIAA. I will check their guidelines.

Comment: On reproducibility, one thing is that the work is about a simulation, not an experiment, per se. The hardware parameter doesn't effect the functioning of the simulation, which is the focus of the paper -- it's a detail about the system we are modeling.

Comment: @LAM A simulation is very often called a _numerical experiment_ it hence is an experiment, and experiments, to be meaningful, have to be reproducible.